# pythonw.exe in python 3.9

Tags: python, windows, python-3.9, pythonw

I'm learning to code with python 3.9, but the resources I'm using are referred to a previous build. In one of the exercises I'm supposed to use pythonw.exe to run a script in the background, however I don't have such file in my installation folder.

After searching online, I have found that the file must have been automatically deleted by the antivirus during the install. So I uninstalled and reinstalled again while disabling the antivirus during the install (malwarebytes + win defender), but pythonw is still missing.

At this point I don't know if there is another workaround or if there is an alternative to pythonw for version 3.9.. Anyone can help shed some light?

Comment: pythonw is a third-party package: https://pypi.org/project/pythonw/

Comment: @Barmar that package is at least suspicious, starting with being OS-independent, having no description, etc. Perhaps malicious too. `pythonw.exe` is the same to `python.exe` as `javaw.exe` is to `java.exe`: it doesn't open a console window, on Windows. And it's included even in the embeddable package, https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-embeddable-package

Comment: OP: you can just try running your code with `python.exe`, the difference is having/not having an extra console window appearing on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

`pythonw.exe` should be in the same directory as `python.exe`. For me (running Python 3.8) that is `C:\Program Files\Python38`. With a different install option, it probably would be in `C:\Python38`. (Yours would presumably have "`Python39`" where I have "`Python38`".)

Did you get your Python installation file from python.org? It should include `pythonw.exe`; if you got your distribution from somewhere else, it may be tailored differently.

The difference between `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe` is that `pythonw.exe` will avoid opening an extra window. If you don't care about that, go ahead and use `python.exe`.

By the way, I have both MalwareBytes and Windows Defender installed, and neither of those have ever deleted `pythonw.exe` for me, so I doubt that's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually 5 minutes after posting the question I found the solution.

I reinstalled python enabling the option "install for all users". Now the file is there..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's probably not the reason. "install for all users" changes the install so that Python (3.9) is installed into C:\Python39 instead of C:\Program Files\Python39; but should *not* affect what files are installed.